# Use of useEffects to set data using GraphQL in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, frontend, rerender

In my current app i am using GraphQL with apollo. This is currently how im calling my data and setting it within components

```
      useEffect(() => {

      getDataId({
        variables: {
          seriesId: parseInt(id),
        },
  }, [getDataId,id]);



    useEffect(() => {
    if (data && !loading && !error) {
      setReviewsData(data);
      setTotalReviews(data.size);
    }
  }, [data, loading, error]);
```

So im calling one use effect to call the api and then another to set the data when the data is returned.

I feel like this is a bad use and causing multiple rerenders throughout my app as i am doing this multiple times across multiple components.

is there a more performance based way about to call my apis?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `useEffect` with Apollo-Client unless you are setting derived state variables, in your case the number of reviews. If you are doing something like filtering or sorting the data then you can `useMemo` to memo-ify the transformation.

Example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(MYQUERY, options);
  
  useEffect (() => setTotalReviews(data?.myQueryName?.reviews?.length),
    [data?.myQueryName?.reviews])

  const filteredData = useMemo(() => data?.myQueryName?.reviews?.filter(filterFunction),
    [data?.myQueryName?.reviews]
  );

  if (loading) return <Spinner />
  else if (error) return <ErrorComponent error={error}/>
  else if (data) return <ListComponent data={data.myQueryName?.reviews?} />
}
```